# preg_repalce php regex - replacing everything starting with "(" or ending with ")"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I replace every string starting with a ( or ending with a ) in php with preg_replace?

Comment: Why use preg_replace when all you need to do is look at first or last char of string?

Comment: What do you want to replace it with, what did you try? What does not work?

Comment: It's unclear, it isn't a good question! There are no example and you don't show what you have already tried. Your question will be closed without answer. Edit that quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this.

```
If(substr($str,0,1) == "(" || substr($str, -1) == ")") { 
    // Replace string
    $str = "hello world";
}
```

Test it here: https://3v4l.org/g9iYc

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the characters and compare the lengths of the strings with [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php): if they're equal, the string doesn't start or end in a parentheses and viceversa:

```
if (strlen(trim($sample, "()")) !== strlen($sample)) {
    // do your logic
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/9DFBD)

Answer (score 0):

It's usually done like this `preg_replace( '/^[(]|[)]$/g', "add replacement", $target );`

Comment: Not sure, but I think that "string" in the question means "substring".

Comment: I would use this then `(?<!\S) [(] | [)] (?!\S)`

Comment: Really? He wants to replace the whole substring.